# If statement only executing the first condition and running others but no results

Tags: javascript, php

I am using the following php code to run some queriers against my database.

```
if ($Name !="" && $newName !=""){ 
    $sql = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET P_NAME = '$newName' WHERE P_Name = '$Name'";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo 'name was run';
}
if($Name !="" && $Description !=""){
    $sql = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET P_Description = '$Description' WHERE P_NAME = '$Name'";
    $conn->exec($sql); 
    echo 'des worked';
}
if($Name !="" && $Price !=""){
    $sql = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET P_Price = '$Price' WHERE P_NAME = '$Name'";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo 'price worked';
}
if ($Name !="" && $newQuant!=""){
    $sql = "UPDATE PRODUCTS SET P_Quantity = '$newQuant' WHERE P_NAME = '$Name'";
    $conn->exec($sql);
    echo 'quant worked';
}
```

when i use this in the form using `action=` all the updates work taking the values from the form and using them in the code. However I am now trying to use the following javascript code to insert the data but it is only taking the first condition and working. The else if conditions run with no error but do not pass the data through. Can anyone see why this is?

```
function editData(){
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var name = document.getElementById("orginalName");
    var newName = document.getElementById("newName");
    var Description = document.getElementById("newDescription");
    var Price = document.getElementById("newPrice");
    var Quant = document.getElementById('newQuantity');
    if (name.value !="" && newName.value !="" ){
        xmlhttp.open("POST","editForm.PHP",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("Name=" + name.value + "&newName=" + newName.value);
    }
    else if (name.value !="" && Description.value !=""){
        xmlhttp.open("POST","editForm.PHP",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("Name=" + name.value + "&Description=" + Description.value);
    }
    else if (name.value !="" && Price.value !=""){
        xmlhttp.open("POST","editForm.PHP",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("Name=" + name.value + "&Price=" + Price.value);
    }
    else if (name.value !="" && Quant.value !=""){
        xmlhttp.open("POST","editForm.PHP",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("Name=" + name.value + "&newQuant=" + Quant.value);
    }
    else{
        alert("please enter some data");
    }
}

submitButton = document.getElementById("editButton");
submitButton.addEventListener("click", editData);
```

below is the form the JS uses:

```
<form id="dataForm" method="post">
  <h2 id="formheader"> Edit Product</h2>
    <div>
      <label>Product Name:</label>
      <input class="inputForm" id="orginalName" type="text" name="Name">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>New Name:</label>
      <input class="inputForm" id="newName" type="text" name="newName">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>New Description:</label>
      <input class="inputForm" id="newDescription" type="text" name="description">
    </div>
    <div>
      <label>New Price:</label>
      <input class="inputForm" id="newPrice" type="text" name="Price">
    </div>
    <div>
    <label>New Quantity:</label>
    <input class="inputForm" id="newQuantity" type="text" name="quantity">
  </div> 
    <div id="theSubmit">
      <button id="editButton">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</section>
```

Comment: `else if` means only do this test if the previous `if` failed.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `if` is working fine but `else if` is not. It is the point of `else if`. It only checks for this condition if previos `if` or `else if` fails.

Comment: yes sorry, i have not explained myself clearly, i understand how if and else if works but i want it to check to see if `name.value !="" && newName.value !=""` and if that is false then check the else if, and it is doing that but i meant the passing of the data is not working in the else if's sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS code uses a cascaded if, while your php code consists of individual conditionals processed one after another.

Remove all `else` keywords. The last else branch will need a different guard.

So your JS code should look like this:

```
    //..
    var Quant = document.getElementById('newQuantity');
    var data_seen = false;
        // this is a flag to record whether any data has been seen. Used in the guard ofthe alert statement.
    if (name.value !="" && newName.value !="" ){
        data_seen = true;
        xmlhttp.open("POST","editForm.PHP",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("Name=" + name.value + "&newName=" + newName.value);
    }
    if (name.value !="" && Description.value !=""){
        data_seen = true;
        xmlhttp.open("POST","editForm.PHP",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("Name=" + name.value + "&Description=" + Description.value);
    }
    if (name.value !="" && Price.value !=""){
        data_seen = true;
        xmlhttp.open("POST","editForm.PHP",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("Name=" + name.value + "&Price=" + Price.value);
    }
    if (name.value !="" && Quant.value !=""){
        data_seen = true;
        xmlhttp.open("POST","editForm.PHP",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send("Name=" + name.value + "&newQuant=" + Quant.value);
    }
    if (!data_seen) {
        alert("please enter some data");
    }
    //...
```

Comment: thank you, i understand what you have done, however i just tried this and run it and the first if statement gave me the correct result, however when i tested the second, third and fourth if statement they have not passed the data through to perform the update statements, do you know why this may be?

Comment: Have you checked the values of  `Price`, `Description`, `Quant` in your JS at the time of url construction ? Can you post some of the html on which the JS operates?

Comment: yeah i will edit the question and post the forms on which the js takes inputs from

Comment: how can i check the values of `Price`, `Description` and `Quant` at the time of url construction @collapsar